# How to see deleted changes between commits

Tags: git, logging, diff, blame

I am using a repository for a tex files. By using wrong software I have now inconsistent files.

My question is how to see deleted changes between commits. I have narrowed the problem down to about 30 commits in 3 branches. Between those I would like to see the changes to all files in all lines. Especially those lines were added but later disappeared.

Sadly I have whole paragraph in one line, so I may need the word comparison instead of line as well.

**Let say I have commits:**

- Comm5
- Comm4
- Comm3
- Comm2
- Comm1

and I want to see the added lines between `Comm1` and `Comm5` that has not existed in `Comm1` and no longer exist in `Comm5`

I am ok, with the result where I would have all lines duplicated and I would have to manually correct them, I just don't want to miss anything.

Any Advice?

Comment: (1) `git log` you will see 5 hashstring of commit, for example `aaaa000` and `bbbb000`. (2) `git diff aaaa000 bbbb000 path_of_file_need_comparing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the commits are contiguous, `git log`'s [`--patch` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_generating_patches_with_p) can be useful here:

```
git log --patch commit1 commit5
```

will show commit messages alongside diffs for each commit.

Alternatively, it might be better to constrain by file instead of by commit:

```
git log --patch -- my-file.tex
```